# Excute a command in the cmd from c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I want to run multiple CMD command from C# application.

The command on the cmd is like that "C:\Users\Sara Mamdouh\Desktop\New folder> hvite -T 01 -C hcon.con -w net dict hmm_list Ann.wav".

My question is how to call this command from the C# application and also receive the results  in a string?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: `C:\Users\Sara Mamdouh\Desktop\New folder>` is just informative output in the console window indicating the current folder. It can not be part of the command. You need to issue a `CD` before the `hvite` command.

Comment: how to do so @ThorstenDittmar?

Comment: @SonerGönül provided a solution issuing a `CD`. My solution instead uses absolut path names.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should write this in a `bat` file and save it as a like `bat.bat`.

```
cd \
cd C:\Users\Sara Mamdouh\Desktop\New folder
exit
```

You can use [`Process.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) method after that.

> Starts a process resource by specifying the name of an application and
>   a set of command-line arguments, and associates the resource with a
>   new Process component.

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
ps.FileName = "path to bat.bat";
ps.RedirectStandardInput = true;
ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
ps.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "hvite -T 01 -C hcon.con -w net dict hmm_list Ann.wav";
p.StartInfo = ps;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I know the OP wrote this in his question, but the "C:\...>" part is what he sees in the console window and can not be part of the command.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar You are totally right! It can't be a part of the command. Update is coming..

Comment: This is the output that appears on the screen "c:\users\sara mamdouh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HTK\HTK\bin\Debug". This doesn't include the required results. Where HTK is the application name.

Comment: It doesn't work, there is exception "The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams."

Comment: I need help! There isn't any output that appear on the cmd.

Comment: I printed out the output it changed the directory but didn't execute the "hvite" command. The output was "C:\Users\Sara Mamdouh\Desktop\New folder>exit".

Comment: Thx, but can u help me out on this please!!

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) for the `Process` class.

As the informative output `C:\Users\Sara Mamdouh\Desktop\New folder>` you see in the console window may not be part of the command you're issuing, you need to add the absolute path names to the command, so the files can be found:

```
var cmd = @"\"<path to hvite>\hvite\" -T 01 -C hcon.con -w net dict hmm_list \"C:\Users\Sara Mamdouh\Desktop\New folder\Ann.wav\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmd);
```

Comment: What's not clear? When you open up the Windows Console you see the "path part" from above. This, however, is not part of the commands you issue - it's only there that you know in which folder you are. When you issue a command from your own application, it's best to use absolute path names whenever possible. This is what I'm saying above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method if you just need to start a process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd" "whatever parameters");
```

For reading the output, look at the examples on the MSDN page for `Process.StandardOutput`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

Basically, instead of just calling `Process.Start`, you create a new `Process` object with the required parameters, call `Start()` on it and then read the output as in the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cmd = @"hvite -T 01 -C hcon.con -w net dict hmm_list Ann.wav";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", cmd);
```